# PDO + MySQL: PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know this is probably ends up being a typo somewhere but I've tried to debug my syntax for two days and I've searched numerous discussion boards and stack overflow questions to no avail.

When I try to execute the following

```
 try {
        $cnnxn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_username, $db_password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("ERROR: " . $e->getMessage());
    }



    $query1 = "INSERT INTO reply_statistics (reply_id, assignment_id, cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5, cat6, cat7, cat8) VALUES (:replyid, :assid, :cat1, :cat2, :cat3, :cat4, :cat5, :cat6, :cat7, :cat8)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY 
              UPDATE reply_statistics SET `cat1`=:cat1, `cat2`=:cat2, `cat3`=:cat3, `cat4`=:cat4, `cat5`=:cat5, `cat6`=:cat6, `cat7`=:cat7, `cat8`=:cat8  WHERE `reply_id`=:replyid";

    $query2 = "UPDATE replies SET status=:status, corrected_reply=:correply, score=:score WHERE id=:replyid";

    $cnnxn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $cnnxn->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
    $query = $cnnxn->prepare($query1);
    $query->bindParam(':replyid', $replyid);
    $query->bindParam(':assid', $assid);
    $query->bindParam(':cat1', $cat1);
    $query->bindParam(':cat2', $cat2);
    $query->bindParam(':cat3', $cat3);
    $query->bindParam(':cat4', $cat4);
    $query->bindParam(':cat5', $cat5);
    $query->bindParam(':cat6', $cat6);
    $query->bindParam(':cat7', $cat7);
    $query->bindParam(':cat8', $cat8);
    $query->execute();

    if ($query !== false)
                {
                    $statusreport = "OK";
                }

if($statusreport == "OK"){
  $query = $cnnxn->prepare($query2);
  $query->bindParam(':replyid', $replyid);
    $query->bindParam(':correply', $correply);
    $query->bindParam(':status', $status);
    $query->bindParam(':score', $score);
    $query->execute();

        if ($query !== false)
                {
                    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\">Tallennettu.</div>";
                }

}


$cnnxn = null;
```

I get this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET `cat1`='0', `cat2`='0', `cat3`='0', `cat4`='0', `cat5`='0', `cat6`='0', `cat' at line 3' in /[CENSORED]/do-review.php:56 Stack trace: #0 /[CENSORED]/do-review.php(56): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /[CENSORED]/do-review.php on line 56
```

It connects fine and the variables set quite nicely, but it fails on the `INSERT -- ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause.

About the table structure: `reply_id` is unique, but there is also a separate `id` column, which is a primary key with auto increment.

Comment: you're trying to bind from 2 separate queries and using the same bind

Comment: Please elaborate. :)

Comment: Ah sorry Ralph, I got stuck in before I saw you were on it @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to treat the ON DUPLICATE set of parameters as totally seperately named parameters, even though you may use the same variables to bind data to them. And the query syntax was a little bit out of wack.

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO reply_statistics 
               (reply_id, assignment_id, 
                cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, 
                cat5, cat6, cat7, cat8) 
           VALUES (:replyid, :assid, 
                   :cat1, :cat2, :cat3, :cat4, 
                   :cat5, :cat6, :cat7, :cat8)
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                  `cat1`=:cat1a, `cat2`=:cat2a, 
                  `cat3`=:cat3a, `cat4`=:cat4a, `cat5`=:cat5a, 
                  `cat6`=:cat6a, `cat7`=:cat7a, `cat8`=:cat8a ";


$query = $cnnxn->prepare($query1);

$query->bindParam(':replyid', $replyid);
$query->bindParam(':assid', $assid);
$query->bindParam(':cat1', $cat1);
$query->bindParam(':cat2', $cat2);
$query->bindParam(':cat3', $cat3);
$query->bindParam(':cat4', $cat4);
$query->bindParam(':cat5', $cat5);
$query->bindParam(':cat6', $cat6);
$query->bindParam(':cat7', $cat7);
$query->bindParam(':cat8', $cat8);
// parametes for the ON DUP set of params
$query->bindParam(':cat1a', $cat1);
$query->bindParam(':cat2a', $cat2);
$query->bindParam(':cat3a', $cat3);
$query->bindParam(':cat4a', $cat4);
$query->bindParam(':cat5a', $cat5);
$query->bindParam(':cat6a', $cat6);
$query->bindParam(':cat7a', $cat7);
$query->bindParam(':cat8a', $cat8);
```

Comment: Thank you, but the error message is still the same.  (Well, because there are new lines, now the line number in the error message is different, but it is still pointing to the same point in the code as previously).

Comment: Is the `reply_id` a auto-increment column as well as being unique

Comment: Try that, I think you need to use the `assignment_id` in the UPDATE part of the query

Comment: The problem with that suggestion is that `assignment_id` and `reply_id` refer to columns in other tables, and it cannot be predicted in what order they will be entered into this (`reply_statistics`) table. (They are not foreign keys in the table, if you're wondering) Also, once `assignment_id` has been set, there is no need to update it. Do I really need to add it to the UPDATE part as well?

Comment: Its in the WHERE clause, not in the data assignment list

Comment: It seems I need to divulge my whole script here. :D 
1) There is an assignment, let's say id=1
2) There can be multiple replies to that assignment, let's say id=1 and id=2. When a reply is saved, it also contains the assignment id information as `assingment_id`. 
3) These replies can be analysed and these analytics are saved into the `reply_statistics` table. Each row contains both reply id information and assignment id information for analysing purposes (`reply_id` and `assignment_id`, respectively).

So I cannot update based on `assignment_id` as there usually are multiple rows w/ same value

Comment: It seems to me that if you know the `reply_id` and the `assignment_id` then you pretty much know this row already exists, so in that case why are you writing the query like this

Comment: I updated my previous comment. As I said, I cannot update on `assignment_id` value and cannot use auto increment with `reply_id` - I cannot even try it. It would break my DB.

Comment: In that case a simple SELECT did I find it? Yes UPDATE No INSERT might be a better solution. Although I admit I dont totally understand your situation

Comment: I'm trying to use the same PHP script to do both of these: A) there is no previous entry, let's create one B) there already is a row that matches the criteria, let's update that.

Comment: Would you show the table as SQL so I can whip it into my test database to see if I can get a better handle on the issue, and maybe a few lines of data in it, and a few lines you want to upidate it with

Comment: Wow, talk about dedication. Thanks! :) CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reply_statistics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reply_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `assignment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat6` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat8` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `reply_id` (`reply_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Comment: Can you edit your question, makes it easier to read/copy I kinda got gripped by the challenge

Comment: _Face Palm!!!! Face Palm!!!! Face Palm!!!!_, I was obviously not paying attention to the basic query syntax which was wrong. Check the amended query. And removed the unnecessary last 2 parameter bindings

Comment: Hallelujah! :D 
I can see the logic now that you have pointed the error in my ways! Thanks a MILLION!